# GetListAndView not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

I have just started sharepoint development using cloudshare.  Now i am stuck trying to run the code below:

```
myListService.Url = "http://sp2010/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

XmlNode myListView = myListService.GetListAndView("Customers", "");
```

I get an exception on the second line saying something like "ListNotFound"

I have tried different web ref urls, but still not working e.g.

> 'http://sp2010/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx'
>
> 'http://sp2010:8080/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx'
>
> 'http://localhost/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx'

This is my page url -

> 'http://sp2010:8080/personal/joe/SitePages/Home.aspx'

If i try this with Tasks it works fine, but when i call 'GetListItems' it is empty (even though i have manually added some).

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I dunno if the url that you are passing is correct.. can you try the following?

The code is getting the true url and adding the webservice at the end. It should return the correct webservice url regardless of what it is :)

```
string hostURL = null;
hostURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

hostURL = hostURL + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

myListService.Url = hostURL;

XmlNode myListView = myListService.GetListAndView("Customers", "");
```

Hope it helps :)